# Clumped scattered data points due to 1e8 notation in seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a series of values like that with 80 entries.

```
Index      Value
35        100000
77      20000000
94         83400
153     12700000
189        82600
          ...   
7118      132050
7200        1800
7240      257710
7409    40000000
7736     1000000
```

When I plot it against a categorical variable it produces this 1e8 notation and squeezes most of my values around the 0.0 y tick label.

[image]

My code:

```
f,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
ax=sb.swarmplot(x=df['col1'], y=df['col2'], data=df)
```

How can I not have this 1e8 notation and spread my scatter points they can be distinctively visualized?

UPDATE: I included ax.set(yscale="log") and edited the y_tick_labels and it looks better. Thanks all.

```
ax.set(yscale="log")
ax.set_yticklabels(['100','1000','10000','100,000','1,000,000','10mil','100mil'])
```

[image]

Comment: is log transformation works for you ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using logarithmic scale for your plot:

```
plt.xscale('log')
```

See [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-pyplot-py) for more details.

Or in seaborn:

```
f,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
ax.set(xscale="log")
ax=sb.swarmplot(x=df['col1'], y=df['col2'], data=df)
```